# How to convert Font Awesome IconDefinition to Kendo UI SVGIcon

Tags: angular, svg, kendo-ui

Kendo UI recently just moved to using SVG icons by default in their widgets ([link](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/future-icons-telerik-kendo-ui-themes)), but their selection of [icons](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/icons/svgicon/svgicon-list/) is not very good.  I would like to use [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/) icons instead, but they have different variable types.  How can I do this?

- [Kendo UI Icon Component](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/icons/api/IconComponent/)
- [Font Awesome Icon Defintion](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/0698449d50f2b95517562295a59d414afc68b369/js-packages/%40fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types/index.d.ts#L13)

Answer (score 1):

I reached out to Telerik's support and they helped me:

**My Code**

```
import { SVGIcon } from '@progress/kendo-svg-icons';

import { faHouse } from '@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons';

public faHouse: SVGIcon = {
    name: faHouse.iconName,
    content: `<path d="${faHouse.icon[4]}" />`,
    viewBox: `0 0 ${faHouse.icon[0]} ${faHouse.icon[1]}`,
};
```

[Their Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xco7qi).

Comment: You still have one file for every icon then. Might as well dump all info in one file, and include the definition for a ``<svg-icon is="...">`` native Web Component